# Send order shipping and billing address to a payment gateway

Tags: sylius, payum

In our project we need to integrate a custom payment gateway. We need to do SOAP calls to the gateway and in the call to make the payment, we need to include several data related to the order like shipping and billing Address.

Working with Sylius and Payum, wich should be the best way to get this data from the order? maybe injecting the order repository in the Convert or CaptureAction and get the order data from there?

Answer (score 2):

sorry, now i found that i can get the order from the Payment. 
With this i can get all the data i need.